# Directory Searcher

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

This is about my first backbone.js application. It is a small directory that fetches data and presents it in a search-like UI.

[Here](http://nativomorphosis.cl/prui/index.html) is a working (minified) example.

Here is the file that handles everything

```
window.Directory = function() {
    "use strict";

    // Create the view and listen to main events
    this.view = new this.AppView().on({
        // Main functions that take care of searching and returning results for multiple items.
        'Dir.parseForm':                    function() { this.parseForm() },
        'Dir.parsedTheForm':                function(selectedThings) { this.prepareResultsCollection(selectedThings) },
        'Dir.resultsCollectionPrepared':    function() { this.collection.fetch() },
        'Dir.fetchingThings':               function() {}, // Just here in case we need it
        'Dir.doneFetching':                 function() { this.createArrayOfElements() },
        'Dir.elementsReadyToInsert':        function(elementsToInsert) { this.insertIntoTheDOM(elementsToInsert) }, // We're all done.

        // Functions for handling when a single element wants to be viewed.
        'Dir.clickedElement':               function(clickEvent) { this.getClickedId(clickEvent) },
        'Dir.gotClickedElementId':          function(clickedId) { this.prepareClickedModel(clickedId) },
        'Dir.clickedModelPrepared':         function() { this.model.fetch() },
        'Dir.fetchingModel':                function() {},
        'Dir.doneFetchingModel':            function() { this.createModelElement(); },
        'Dir.modelReadyToInsert':           function(modelElement) { this.insertModelElementInDOM(modelElement) },


        // A little spinner
        'Dir.spinnerOn':                    function(spinnerMessage) {
                                                switch(spinnerMessage) {
                                                    case 'wait': var spinnerHTML = '<b class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></b>'; break;
                                                    case 'load': var spinnerHTML = '<b class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></b>'; break;
                                                    default: var spinnerHTML = spinnerMessage;
                                                }
                                                jQuery('#ai-info').html(spinnerHTML);
                                            },
        'Dir.spinnerOff':                   function() { jQuery('#ai-info').empty() }
    });
}

Directory.prototype.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '[data-main]',
    results_area: '[data-results]',
    events: {
        // Switches that trigger the search action
        'change [name="type"]':             function() { this.trigger('Dir.parseForm') },
        'keyup  [name="keyword"]':          function() { this.trigger('Dir.parseForm') },
        'change [name="specialization"]':   function() { this.trigger('Dir.parseForm') },
        'change [name="sector"]':           function() { this.trigger('Dir.parseForm') },
        'change [name="size"]':             function() { this.trigger('Dir.parseForm') },
        'change [name="startswith"]':       function() { this.trigger('Dir.parseForm') },

        // On click a single element
        'click [data-id]':                  function(clickedElement) { this.trigger('Dir.clickedElement', clickedElement) }
    },
    // We set a timeout here so that this trigger is done asynchronously, and the event bindings can be ready.
    initialize: function() { setTimeout(function(){ this.trigger('Dir.parseForm')}.bind(this) )},

    /***
     * Returns an array of the selected form elements using
     * Backbone.Syphon.serialize(). Additionally, sets a timer
     * function to avoid submitting when the user is typing.
     */
    parseForm: function() {
        // Set our spinner to 'waiting'
        this.trigger('Dir.spinnerOn', 'wait');
        // To avoid multiple requests when typing we set a timeout that clears itself under 500ms
        clearTimeout(this.safeType); this.safeType = setTimeout(function () {
            // Create object of items based on the selected items from the filters form.
            var selectedThings = Backbone.Syphon.serialize(this);
            // Let the event handler know we're ready.
            this.trigger('Dir.parsedTheForm', selectedThings);
        }.bind(this), 500);
    },

    /***
     * Creates a collection object to store the objects that
     * will be shown. It is called when 'Dir.parsedTheForm' is
     * triggered.
     * @param selectedThings
     */
    prepareResultsCollection: function(selectedThings) {
        // We set the URL our Backbone.Collection is going to use.
        switch (selectedThings.type) {
            case "product": var url = '/api/category';break;
            case "service": var url = '/api/category';break;
            default:        var url = '/api/company';
        }
        // Create a little Backbone collection and bind a few events
        this.collection = new Backbone.Collection();
        this.collection.url = url;
        this.collection.type = selectedThings.type; // For templating
        this.collection.comparator = 'name';
        this.collection.on({
            'request':  function() {
                this.trigger('Dir.spinnerOn', 'load')
                this.trigger('Dir.fetchingThings')
            },
            'sync':     function() {
                this.trigger('Dir.doneFetching');
                this.trigger('Dir.spinnerOff');
            }
        }, this); // Note that we're binding the view as the 'this' variable.
        // Let the event handler know we're done.
        this.trigger('Dir.resultsCollectionPrepared');
    },
    /***
     * Creates an array of elements ready to be inserted in the DOM
     * from the results provided in the this.collection.models array.
     * Creates the array 'elements', fires up Dir.elementsReadyToInsert
     * and is fired up with Dir.doneFetching.
     */
    createArrayOfElements: function() {
        // First let's determine what template we're using
        switch (this.collection.type) {
            case "product":
            case "service": var templateTagId = 'template-category';break;
            default:        var templateTagId = 'template-company';
        }
        // Go through the models contained in the collection and generate an HTML for each one
        var elementsToInsert = []; this.collection.models.forEach(function(littleModel) {
            // Find the template in the HTML that has the id #template-{collection type}
            var templateTag = document.getElementById(templateTagId),
                template = _.template( templateTag.innerHTML.trim() ),
                html = template( littleModel.toJSON() );

            elementsToInsert.push(html);
        }.bind(this));
        // And let the event handler know we're ready.
        this.trigger('Dir.elementsReadyToInsert', elementsToInsert);
    },
    /***
     * This function takes the array of elements built by #createArrayOfElements
     * and inserts them into the DOM. Fired by 'Dir.elementsReadyToInsert'.
     * @param elementsToInsert
     */
    insertIntoTheDOM: function(elementsToInsert) {
        // Create a wrapper element to collect each one, and insert the wrapper in the results area.
        switch (this.collection.type) {
            case "product": var wrapperHTML = '<div class="categories"></div>';break;
            case "service": var wrapperHTML = '<div class="categories"></div>';break;
            default:        var wrapperHTML = '<table class="table table-hover table-condensed companies"></table>';
        }
        var $wrapper = jQuery(wrapperHTML); jQuery(this.results_area).html($wrapper);
        // Insert each element into the wrapper.
        elementsToInsert.forEach(function(elementHTML) { $wrapper.append(elementHTML) }.bind(this))
    },
    /***
     * This function just finds the clicked element id when there's a click event
     * on an element with a [data-id] attribute. It's fired by the Dir.clickedElement
     * event and sends Dir.gotClickedElementId when it's done.
     * @param clickEvent
     */
    getClickedId: function(clickEvent) { // This comes from a click event
        // Find the [data-id] attribute using jQuery
        var clickedElement = clickEvent.currentTarget,
            clickedId = jQuery(clickedElement).attr('data-id');
        // This is a little patch that does no harm, to avoid looping when seeing companies inside categories
        this.collection.type = jQuery(clickedElement).attr('data-type') || this.collection.type;
        // Let the event handler know we have it.
        this.trigger('Dir.gotClickedElementId', clickedId);
    },
    /***
     * This function takes the clicked element's id and forms a little model from it,
     * with the url set to properly fetch its data. When it's done, it fires
     * Dir.clickedModelPrepared. The function itself is fired by Dir.prepareClickedModel.
     * @param clickedId
     */
    prepareClickedModel: function(clickedId) {
        // Let's set the URL that the model is going to use. Using switch instead of getting it from this.collection.url to allow configuration afterwards.
        switch (this.collection.type) {
            case "product": var url = '/api/category';break;
            case "service": var url = '/api/category';break;
            default:        var url = '/api/company';
        }
        // Create a little model associated with the given Id through the url parameter, and register a few events.
        this.model = new Backbone.Model();
        this.model.url = url + '/' + clickedId;
        this.model.on({
            'request':  function() {
                this.trigger('Dir.spinnerOn', 'load');
                this.trigger('Dir.fetchingModel')
            },
            'sync':     function() {
                this.trigger('Dir.doneFetchingModel');
                this.trigger('Dir.spinnerOff');
            }
        }, this);
        // Let the event handler know we're done.
        this.trigger('Dir.clickedModelPrepared');
    },
    /***
     * Creates the HTML element for the clicked model, and dispatches it ready
     * to be inserted in the DOM. Fires up Dir.modelReadyToInsert, and
     * it's fired up by Dir.doneFetchingModel.
     */
    createModelElement: function() {
        // Based on the collection we came from, we can determine the template
        switch (this.collection.type) {
            case "product":
            case "service": var templateTagId = 'template-category-single';break;
            default:        var templateTagId = 'template-company-single';
        }
        // Find the template in the HTML that has corresponding id.
        var templateTag = document.getElementById(templateTagId),
            template = _.template( templateTag.innerHTML.trim() ),
            modelElement = template( this.model.toJSON() );
        // Let the event handler know we're done.
        this.trigger('Dir.modelReadyToInsert', modelElement);
    },
    /***
     * Inserts the clicked model element into the DOM. Fired up by Dir.modelReadyToInsert.
     * @param modelElement
     */
    insertModelElementInDOM: function(modelElement) {
        jQuery(this.results_area).html(modelElement);
    }
});

var dir = new Directory();
```

My main concerns are:

- I have not used any module loading library.
- I am more or less *freestyling* in respect to code structure.
- I'm using jQuery just for a few functions like `$.attr()` and `$.html()`.
- I'm *kind of* using backbone.js in a way that (I think) it's not really intended for.
- Things like

  ```
  this.view = new this.AppView().on({
  ```

  ```
  case "service": var templateTagId = 'template-category-single';break;
  ```
- Initializing models and collections on the go.

Things I feel proud of but are probably bad news:

- Using events for everything instead of chaining functions.
- So many comments

Could someone offer a code review on patterns, structure, style, and general quality of the solution?

Answer (score 5):

Interesting code. As you might have guessed, there's a lot wrong with it.

- Events instead of chaining. Makes it harder to follow the code, makes it harder on IDE's that know how to jump to a function, no added benefits.  You have `this` basically as a holder of global variables instead of calling functions with parameters
- Comments -> I like it, but be careful with things like this:

  ```
  /***
   * Inserts the clicked model element into the DOM. Fired up by Dir.modelReadyToInsert.
   * @param modelElement
   */
  insertModelElementInDOM: function(modelElement) {
      jQuery(this.results_area).html(modelElement);
  }
  ```

  I understand you call this function with the clicked model element, but really you want to document what the function does, not with what it is called.
- `this.view = new this.AppView().on({` -> Oh my goodness, because you are abusing events, that parts looks terrible with the lack of newlines, I am not sure you can salvage it without keeping only the *real* events.
- Regardless, `'Dir.parseForm': function() { this.parseForm() },` could be `'Dir.parseForm': this.parseForm,`
- `Backbone.View.extend({`, the `events` part, has a ton of copy pasted `function() { this.trigger('Dir.parseForm') },`, you should do something about that
- You are not using a module loading library -> I think that's ok
- Except for abuse of chaining, I think your code structure is fine
- jQuery -> better than writing and maintaining `attr` & `html` yourself I would think
- Creating Models on the fly -> yeah, it looks wrong to me, you are supposed to declare your model once and then get instances.

All in all, I am sorry to say that most of this code should be rewritten to stop abusing events/listeners.

Comment: Thank you for the comments! Actually, this is version 2 of the code. Version one was a mess. I will apply your recommendations and probably make an update of the results. Thanks again !

Comment: @AlainJacometForte Just a note: If you edit your code and want a new review of it, please post it as a completely new question to avoid confusion.